# To emerge as a pioneer/leader for sth. VS to become a pioneer/leader for sth

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if those above mentioned key phrases are correct. Can you help me?

What I would like to say:

> "How Germany emerges as a pioneer/leader for sustainability in Europe, finding innovative solutions for challenges in the energy sector."

Is there a more attractive way to express what I'd like to say?

Comment: It's down to your personal stylistic preference - but obviously ***emerging*** more strongly implies *visibly, to the wider public, media, and/or other interested parties*, whereas you could ***become*** a "pioneer" whilst working alone and unknown in your bedroom or garage.

Comment: Note that this is probably not a grammatically correct sentence anyway (it could be the edge case of someone exclaiming "*How* great Germany is!"). So what *do* you want to say? Please add some context to your question. Maybe you just have to leave the *How* off, but we currently can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

There are some subtle differences between *Pioneer/Leader*, and between *emerge/become*. Which you choose will depend on what meaning you want your statement to carry.

- A **pioneer** is generally someone who was *first* at something, paving the way for others to follow. They may not currently be in the lead.
- A **leader** is someone who is *currently* ahead in a particular field, and setting the way for others to follow. They may not have been the first.

So for example, you could say that people like *Ford* and *Benz* were the pioneers of motor cars. But those names may or may not necessarily be classed as "leaders" today. (I'm no expert - "Ford" still appears in the top 10 leading motor companies, but is not first)

- **Emerge** means to become apparent, visible, or prominent.
- **Become** simply means *to begin to be* something.

In the context you give, when someone is described as "*emerging as leader...*" it normally implies that a leader has emerged after a period of competition between parties. For example, you might say that Google has emerged as the world's leading search engine after a period of competition with companies such as Yahoo (once the leader I believe).

I don't believe it would be appropriate to use either of the above terms along with "pioneer" for the reasons I give above - if you are the *first* at something, you were the first, end of. You can't "emerge" as first because there was nobody else to rise above. But either of "*became leader...*" or "*emerged as leader...*" seem perfectly appropriate, but "*emerged as...*" sounds more like their current position is the result of a period of competition or hard work rather than simply a decision to *become* something.

You have asked for a way to phrase the following:

> "How Germany emerges as a pioneer/leader for sustainability in Europe, finding innovative solutions for challenges in the energy sector."

Following my logic, if you are trying to say that Germany is the *first* to find sustainability solutions then you could rightly called them a "pioneer", and you could phrase it as:

> Germany *is a pioneer* for sustainability in Europe, finding innovative solutions for challenges in the energy sector.

Or if you wanted to say that they have *become* leader *in comparison* to the efforts of other countries, you could say:

> Germany has *emerged as leader* for sustainability in Europe, finding innovative solutions for challenges in the energy sector.

Or lastly, if you wanted to say that they were now leading in the *general field of sustainability* because they pioneered (or were first to use) *specific* solutions, you *could* say:

> Germany has *emerged as leader for sustainability* in Europe, *pioneering innovative solutions* for challenges in the energy sector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am a little bit disappointed though. So, if you won't recommend me to use either of the terms, what would you recommend me?

What I would like to say:

"How Germany emerges as a pioneer/leader for sustainability in Europe, finding innovative solutions for challenges in the energy sector."

Comment: I have added 3 possible examples, but you must read and understand the logic behind them. They could all be correct, but they convey different meanings.